# Can SpringMVC display a star for required form fields?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Is there a way, built-in in Spring MVC, to display an "*" sign beside the required fields of a form?

I've found out how to display error messages in the JSP for missing required values. But before the user submits anything, is there a way to visually tell him "this field is required"?

I could add a "*" sign in the JSP manually. But I'd prefer the custom tags of Spring to do it for me, based on the @NotEmpty validation annotation.

Thanks. John.

Answer (score 0):

No. the nearest you'll get is an error message if submitted and empty. But I'd just roll my own css class that appended text to label element.

Spring Form options :
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.option

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nim's answer, you could bind an

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

Within the function you could check the contents of the different required fields and appending on that label that Nim spoke of.  As long as this function returns false when there are field errors, the form will not submit.